# ReactJS - How do show multiple clickable links in a table cell when data has text+multiple links?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an app with back-end database data displayed in a ReactJS front end app. The data is displayed in a HTML table (rows and columns). One of the columns has text as below:

```
"One http://www.example_1.com/    Two http://www.example_2.com/"
```

This text can have one link or two or three. When I display it in the table cell I want these links to show as clickable hyper links. This is the issue I am trying.

When a column has one link text only , I can code like this in react program. This shows as clickable hyperlink in a table cell (*works fine*):

```
<td><a href={row.link_text}>{row.link_text}</a></td>
```

When I have text with one link like `"Some txt and http://www.example.com/"`, I can convert the text into two sub strings - one with text and one with link text - and show the data in a cell using (*works fine*):

```
<td>{row.text_without_link}<a href={row.link_text}>{row.link_text}</a></td>
```

***How do I*** make the hyperlinks dynamically when the text has multiple links text (one or more)?

Is there is standard way (technique) for this *or* do I have to write lot of code for this in the reactjs program?

I welcome any help and suggestions to solve this. Thank you.

---

The React component class's `render` method looks like this (the table is formatted using HTML and CSS):

```
render() {
    const tableRows = this.props.data.map((row, i) =>
        <tr key={i} >
            <td>{row.some_column}</td>
            <td>{row.text_without_link}<a href={row.link_text}>{row.link_text}</a></td>
        </tr>
    );
    return 
        <table>
            <thead>...</thead>
            <tbody>
                {tableRows}
            </tbody>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render() {
const URL_REGEX =
/^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/gm;

function Text({ content }) {
const words = content.split(' ');
return (
    <p>
        {words.map((word) => {
            return word.match(URL_REGEX) ? (
                <>
                    <a href={word}>{word}</a>{' '}
                </>
            ) : (
                word + ' '
            );
        })}
    </p>
);
}


const tableRows = this.props.data.map((row, i) =>
    <tr key={i} >
        <td>{row.some_column}</td>
        <td>{<Text content={row.column_text}/>}</td>
    </tr>
);
return 
    <table>
        <thead>...</thead>
        <tbody>
            {tableRows}
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer. I will try the code little later and let you know how it worked.

Comment: This works fine for my usage. One thing to note is it is better to use a regex pattern with the string's `split` method.